# Laravel overwrite framework method from middleware or basecontroller

Tags: laravel

```php
Illuminate\View

class Factory {
    public function make($view, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
    {
        //try to overwrite content here
    }
}
```

I have a project need to overwrite vendor/laravel/view/Factory class's method

However I don't want to change the original framework's files.

Is any way I can add a method in middleware or BaseController to overwrite Factory's method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a new class that extends the default Factory class, and overwrite the method there:

```php
class MyFactoryClass extends Factory {
    public function make($view, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
    {
        //Overwrite the method here.
    }
}
```

Now, instead of use the laravel default `Factory` class, use the `MyFactoryClass`.

Hope it helps.